# сцена юнити как переменная

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос: Возможно ли как-то передать сцену в метод кнопки, которая в функции передать в поле что загружать при ее нажатии?

типа. есть у меня сцена 1 уровня и есть кнопка в главном меню, по нажатию которой я должен попадать на этот уровень, и не важно в какой позиции он в Build Settings. как сцену юнити засунуть в поле и использовать в функции?

Comment: [Application.LoadLevel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того, чтобы загружать сцену по индексу - загружайте её по имени. Достаточно изменить `int level` в методе на `string level`.

P.s Важно, чтобы сцена имелась в Build Settings